# Prevent accessing other windows until the current window is closed

Tags: tkinter, python-3.3

I'm writing a GUI, and in this GUI there have to be several windows for editing a config file.

What I want is that users can't use other windows until the active window is close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to do a "grab" on a window, which will force all events to go to that window. The command to do this is [grab_set](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.grab_set-method). If you search for `[tkinter] grab_set` on this site you'll find answers with examples.