A window that does not allow any action to be taken unless the window is closed
I want to display an alert window on the screen using Python tkinter. The user should not be able to do anything without closing this alert window. How can I do this? Like Windows high priority windows that flash and give notification sounds
When the window is opened, it always draws the focus to itself and does not perform any operations in the background.
The pop-up window should restrict access on a system basis rather than an application basis. I tried ways like having the window constantly draw focus, but even if the window always remains on the top layer, it allows different operations to be performed on the system. I don't know if what I'm talking about is possible.
From some research (1 - 2), the following codes are currently available, but they don't achieve the result that I want:
def make_system_modal():
        hwnd = notification_window.winfo_id()
        ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0001 | 0x0002)
        ctypes.windll.user32.EnableWindow(hwnd, True)
        ctypes.windll.user32.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
        ctypes.windll.user32.SetActiveWindow(hwnd)
        ctypes.windll.user32.SetFocus(hwnd)
        notification_window.grab_set_global()

def focus_window():
        if notification_window.winfo_exists():
            notification_window.lift()
            notification_window.focus_force()
            root.update_idletasks()

def keep_focus():
        while notification_active.is_set():
            with lock:
                if not notification_window.winfo_exists():
                    break
            focus_window()
            time.sleep(0.1)



In the early days of Windows this was possible by the use of the SystemModal Window type. However that is no longer available so you cannot prevent the user from taking other actions. It looks like this is a similar question to your previous two on the subject of preventing the user taking their own actions.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363919/prevent-accessing-other-windows-until-the-current-window-is-closed

@BryanOakley, I guess, nope it doesn't, as this Thread is already linked to in the "From some research (1 - 2)" part, the Link #2 already links to that Thread, and OP has already mentioned that notification_window.grab_set_global() doesn't achieve the result that they want... (I had already suggested that Thread as a possible Dupe Target in the Staging Ground.)

Why does notification_window.grab_set_global() not do what you want? What feature is it missing?

It is possible if you use toplevel window instead of messagebox or any other alert window.
I didn't read your functions as I should understand from half the way. Use the following idea and use in yours.
Toplevel_window_name.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", function_to_be_triggered) triggers the function you want to trigger if you close the toplevel window. Note: Instead of closing the toplevel window the required function will be triggered. So, if you want to close the top level window, you should add toplevel_window_name.destroy() separately.
So, with the following code, when the popup opens, all the widgets in the main window will be disabled. If you close the popup by pressing X, again the widgets in the main window will be enabled. If you want to do something with button press in the toplevel window(taking aan action in toplevel), again all the widgets will be enabled. After doing the required thing if you want to close the toplevel window, uncomment line 21 new.destroy() or if you prefer the user to close, leave it as it is.
from tkinter import *
dct = {}

def pop(): # toplevel

    def on_close():
        enable_widgets()
        new.destroy()

    def enable_widgets():
        ls = [x for x in dct.values()]
        for x in ls:
            if x['state'] == DISABLED:
                x['state'] = NORMAL

    def close_popup():

        # Do something
        enable_widgets()
        # If you want to close popup uncomment the following line
        #new.destroy()


    new = Toplevel(root)
    new.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)
    ls = [x for x in dct.values()]
    for x in ls:
        x['state'] = DISABLED

    btn_2 = Button(new, text = 'Do something', command=close_popup)
    btn_2.pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry('100x200')

dct['entry'] = Entry(root)
dct['entry'].pack()

dct['btn'] = Button(text = 'pop up', command=pop)
dct['btn'].pack()


root.mainloop()


This looks more complicated than necessary. Tkinter has a grab_set method that funnels all events to the popup which makes it impossible to interact with any window but the popup.

Also instead of ls = [x for x in dct.values()] and then for x in ls:, you can instead use for x in dct.values():, it's faster and looks cleaner

@BryanOakley, Thanks. I didn't know abt grab_set method. Thanks for the info. After seeing your message, checked in tk official documents. grab_set is very simple to use. Thanks for the info.

@TheLizzard, though I use to do that, It just depends upon the mood. Sometimes we tend to split into more number of components, and sometimes not. I agree declaring a list is not similar to splitting into multiple variables. But ..

@BryanOakley, btw, Thanks for editing.
